# object oriented properties for new object creation

Tags: oop

When we create new object example there is class Employee.Create a instance of Employee class.

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
```

Which OOPS property this above statement describes

Answer (score -2):

With the statement `Employee emp1 = new Employee();` you are **instantiating** an object of the class Employee and referencing to emp1.

Regards,

Comment: I dont' understand why the answer has been downvoted. Can anybody explain me why? Thanks